# set c-compiler and c++-compiler flags for single target without abusing CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and CMAKE_C_FLAGS

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I've got an (embedded mixed C/C++) project.
I need to set, the most important one, `-fno-rtti`. I can't use

```
target_compile_options(
    my_target

    PRIVATE
       -fno-rtti
)
```

Because this sets -fno-rtti for CXX and C objects. However, watching [Daniel Pfeifer - "Effective CMake"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLopVhns4Zs) he 'recommends' to not use `SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${CUSTOM_C_FLAGS}")` and `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CUSTOM_CXX_FLAGS}")`

But how can I achieve different compiler flags for c++ and c? I can't just use `-fno-rtti` for C, because it emits warnings, warnings that I can't ignore because of `-Werror` policy.

I've tried moving the C files to a library or the C++ files to a library but that generates a different (non working) binary.